# Why does my D Flip Flop Circuit have an X output?

Tags: clock, flipflop

I'm working on one of my projects and I'm having trouble with my flip flops. The project is to design the circuit for a gas pump that has a handle and a sensor. When the handle is down, the pump pumps, but when the sensor is activated, the pump shuts off. It will pump again until a second high pressure is read, at which point the pump shuts down completely until a manual reset is done (not part of the project). I'm working on the Mealey design since it's a little smaller.

Essentially, when my handle is high and my sensor is low, I'm getting an X for my output and I don't know why. I hope someone can provide some input:

Here is everything I have for it:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Alright, I added the reset. Now I'm getting that my states change every time my clock changes. Any ideas?:

[image]

Comment: "It will pump again until a second high pressure is read": do you mean if handle goes to zero and then to 1 again?  In other words, how is the pump restarted after first shut-off?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then yes. Once a high pressure is read while the handle is pulled, the pump goes to 0. The handle must be released and pressed again in order to start pumping until a second high pressure is read. At which point, you cannot pump again.

Comment: If I understand your drawing, your "Handle" input connects only to the AND gate at lower right. And the output of that AND gate goes nowhere. So I don't see any way for the Handle input to affect the state machine.

Comment: @The Photon, because this is a Mealey design where the the states are as follows: S0 = no high pressure warning, S1 = 1 warning, and S2 = 2 warnings, the handle does not effect state transition, only whether or not the machine is pumping. The problem rested in the Set/Reset as Tim mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like your flip flops need to have a reset value.

When power is applied to a DFF at "time=0", the output state is X, or unknown. A reset is needed to bring the DFF to a known state.

In your case, check out the FF `DB`. It's input is:

```
(DB && !DA) || (Sensor && !DB && DA).
```

When I substitute your time zero values into this I get:

```
= (X && !X) || (0 && X && X)
= ( X || 0 )
= X
```

So until something happens that actually forces the inputs to a non-X value, the circuit will have an X state forever. A 'reset' would typically be used to clear the Xs.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. Any suggestions on where best to put a reset?

Comment: Ideally you could replace your DFF with resettable DFFs which have a dedicated reset pin, but if that's not supported to your tool you can add an extra logic gate at the D pin of the flop. If I assume that you want to reset the flops to 0, and have an active low reset `reset_`, then I would just add an AND gate to the D-pin of each flop (`D = original input && reset_`). Then just pull reset low for a clock cycle and the flops will fall to zero. @rphello101

Comment: This did turn out to be my problem. My second problem that I had was in my wiring. My SOP's were correct, but if you look at my wiring, there are a couple wrong connections. Thanks for the advice.